# Change a Method in Java at Runtime

Tags: java, methods, editor

I am writing a little game which uses a skeletal animation. Now for example take the method for walking, which I added in my Skeleton class. Each game tick it is called and the angles of the legs and arms of the model change a bit.

Now what I want is to create an editor where you can write code into a JTextArea on a JFrame and if you confirm your code, the method for walking changes and the skeleton moves as you wrote in the editor.

I put the written code into a string with .getText(), but how can a change the method in the Skeleton class at runtime, so you can instantly test what you wrote in the text area?

I tried to do it with Javaassist, but I didn't got it to work and I now hope that theres a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Provided that re-compiling and running your application does not take huge amounts of time, and since as you said you plan to dispose of this once you find a good solution, I'd say that it would be most unwise to "Construct a car to travel 5 meters, instead of walking there on foot"

Comment: Yes I think you're right. I just hoped there was a simple way to do it. Like "find a boat to cross a brook, instead of making your feet wet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a terrible idea, even if you get it working.  It would allow the user to execute arbitrary code on a system, which is a security risk.  Plus, it's going to require every user to know Java.  Instead, you should allow different options to be selected for the behavior.

Comment: This isn't a problem, because I'm the only person who'll ever make use of this. I'm going to delete this function when I'm satisfied with the movements of the skeleton. I want to be able to do for loops and if statements, so which options could I use for this?

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work for testing code when you could just write the different movements and use a drop down box to choose the one you want to view.  Then you can test them all as needed.  It's not very difficult to edit your code and re-run the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a [Java compiler API](http://www.javabeat.net/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the call of this method and execute a new code.

Try AspectJ http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/sample-code.html